# Fill a DDL using the value by first DDL in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am filling the states DDL using the text in the country DDL

```
   foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
            {
                if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
                {
                    var query = from row in ProfileMasterDAL.bindstate().ToString()
                                where
                                    ProfileMasterDAL.bindstate().ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
                                select row;
                    DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
                    DropDownList2.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

but  at query i am getting Enumeration yields no results and the states DDL is empty.

```
    public static IEnumerable bindstate()
    {
        var states = from b in getdata().Descendants("state").SelectMany(state => state.Elements("text"))
        orderby (string) b
        select (string) b;

        return states;

    }
```

Comment: You are setting the `DataSource` inside a `foreach`, this means that you *may* set it multiple times, which is not a good approach. Also, you are looking if the state contains the country name? That's awkward. Finally, when you debug it, do you ever get inside that `if`?

Comment: Why are you trying to select something from a string?  This ends up being a query against a `char[]`, surely that's not what you want?

Comment: I am looking for country contains the state names.Yes i have gone inside the if condition and im having problem at query.

Comment: What does `ProfileMasterDAL.bindstate()` return?

Comment: IEnumerable collection of states

Comment: @Chandrasekhar  What is the state that it returns, is this a class, just a simple string?  Can you give us the code for this `bindstate()` method?

Comment: No it is a method just check the question i have updated

Comment: @Chandrasekhar Sorry, that doesn't help.  What is the specific type of `states` that is being returned?  `IEnumerable<MyCustomStateClass>`?  `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: @CodingGorilla it is just IEnumerable and im getting the values from a XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so based on comments and the update to your question, I think this is what you want:

```
foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
{
    if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
    {
        var query = from row in ProfileMasterDAL.bindstate()
                    where row.Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
                    select row;
        DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i am unable to get where clause and contains the intellisense unable to show them.

Comment: You can't get IntelliSense because your `bindstate()` method is just returning an `IEnumerable`, there's nothing there for IntelliSense to inspect and give you more information.  If you change that method to return `IEnumerable<XElement>` you will get more information.

Comment: When i change the method to return XElement i am getting an error at return states as  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Chandrasekhar Ok change it back to `IEnumerable` like you had it, and I updated my answer.

Comment: Even though i am getting an error  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'row'.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?